# Is there anyway i can get to know which of my local git branch has been deleted or removed from remote

Tags: git, github

I am looking for a git command that will show me the branches that are deleted in the remote and hence are obsolete in my local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
git branch -a
```

?

This shows you all branches, remote and local.

Comment: I have tried that however , for some reason it shows a remote branch that was not existing in github. It stopped showing that when i freshly cloned the repo. So i am guessing it still looks somewhere local to list the remote branches as well. I may be wrong.

Comment: IIRC, git only updates with remote data, when doing `git pull`

Comment: Ahh, that might be why. Ill keep an eye on that thanks.

Comment: `git fetch` or `git pull`, either way the remote branch list will be updated.